# React-chartjs-2 Doughnut chart export to png

Tags: javascript, png

I have created a Doughnut and Bar chart using react-chartjs-2 library. Now I want to export this chart as png i.e the chart gets downloaded as png on user click. I have tried many ways but could not succeed. One of them was to use html2canvas library and get a screenshot but that is degrading the quality of chart. I am wondering is there any function in react-chartjs-2 library to directly export the chart?

Edit- If someone can tell me about any other library in javascript in which I can make the charts like Bar and Doughnut and that library gives me the function to directly export the chart, that would also be helpful.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Give us examples

Comment: Currently I am using html2canvas library and by using the div id in which the chart is rendered, I am setting my charts onto a canvas and then I am making available the canvas to be downloaded as png. But by using this method, the quality of chart is not good in png.
I am looking for an function in the react-chartjs-2 library to export the chart.

Comment: Have a look around chartjs base64 image. There is a method in chartjs and react-chartjs-2 is a wrapper for react. So either they will have implemented the function or you can call the chartjs function itself.

Comment: Thanks. It helped and I was able to do it using .toBase64Image() function from react-chartjs-2 library itself.
Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to do it using .toBase64Image() function from react-chartjs-2 library itself.

Comment: how did you do that?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using `react-chartjs-2` library, you need to get a ChartJS instance reference and then call `.toBase64Image()` as the other answer suggested. To do that, first create an empty reference:

```
const chartRef = useRef(null);
```

Then, assing the reference. For example, if you are using a `Bar` chart:

```
<Bar data={data} ref={chartRef}/>
```

Finally, get the base64 image using the reference. **Remember to call `.current.chartInstance` before `toBase64Image()`**:

```
const base64Image = chartRef.current.chartInstance.toBase64Image();
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to download the react-chartjs-2 Bar Chart by using the code below. The solution is for the Class component. If you are using a functional component, you can watch this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KuWLhLFfeRc

```
class BarChart extends React.Component {

constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.myRef = React.createRef();
}

clickHandler() {
        const link = document.createElement('a');
        link.download = "chart.jpeg";
        link.href = this.myRef.current.toBase64Image('image/jpeg', 1);
        link.click();
}

render(){
     return(
            <div>
                <button value='print' onClick {this.clickHandler.bind(this)}>Print</button>
                <Bar 
                data={data} 
                options={options}
                ref={this.myRef}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default BarChart;
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's late but stumbled upon this as well and want to give you my code
which exports at **full quality**

```
export const ChartExport = (props: { chart: React.ReactNode; title?: string }) => {
    const chartRef = useRef(null);

    const chartWithRef = React.cloneElement(props.chart, { ref: chartRef });

    const handleDownload = () => {
        const link = document.createElement('a');
        link.download = (props.title ? props.title : 'chart') + '.jpeg';
        link.href = chartRef.current.toBase64Image('image/jpeg', 1); // Here is the magic
        link.click();
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={handleDownload}>
                Download JPEG
            </button>
            {chartWithRef}
        </div>
    );
};
```

Usage

```
<ChartExport title="My awesome chart" chart={<Bar data={myChartDataObj} options={chartOptionsObj} />} />
```