# using react-chartjs-2 , How can I save my chart as png using a download button

Tags: reactjs, chart.js, chart.js2, react-chartjs-2

I'm trying to download my chart.js charts as png using a button Onclick, but I have no idea how I'm going to achieve this , I've went through this answer [React-chartjs-2 Doughnut chart export to png](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62039681/react-chartjs-2-doughnut-chart-export-to-png) but it wasn't quite clear enough for me as I'm quite new in chart.js  don't know how I'm going to connect those variables with my button.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Component, useRef } from 'react';
import { Bar } from 'react-chartjs-2';
import 'chartjs-plugin-datalabels';

const data = {
  labels: ['Finance & Business', 'Mining', 'Community Services', 'Electricity', 'Agriculture', 'Construction', 'Manufacture', "Trade & Tourism", "Transport & Logistics"],
  datasets: [
    {
      label: 'My First dataset',
      backgroundColor: ["#3283FC", "", "", "#00C0C8", "#C0BD00", "#3A46B1", "#00A150", "#FEB200", "#9302a1"],
      borderWidth: 1,
      hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(255,99,132,0.4)',
      hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
      data: [0.6, 0.0, 0.0, -0.1, -0.1, -0.3, -0.3, -0.6, -1.0],
    }
  ]
};


class StackedBar extends Component {

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Bar Example (custom size)</h2>
        <Bar

          data={data}
          options={{
            plugins: {
              datalabels: {
                display: true,
                color: '#fff'
              }
            },
            title: {
              display: true,
              text: 'Contribution Percentage',
              position: 'left'
            },
            maintainAspectRatio: true,
            scales: {
              xAxes: [{

                stacked: true,
                gridLines: {
                  borderDash: [2, 6],
                  color: "black"
                },
                scales: {
                }
              }],
              yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                  beginAtZero: true,
                  steps: 0.5,
                  stepSize: 0.5,
                  max: 1.5,
                  min: -1.0

                },
              }]

            },

          }}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default StackedBar;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I installed a plugin called FileSave.js //

1. npm install
   `npm i file-saver`
2. import the plugin
   `import { saveAs } from 'file-saver';`
3. than just write this blob function

```
   class StackedBar extends Component {
   saveCanvas() {
       //save to png
       const canvasSave = document.getElementById('stackD');
       canvasSave.toBlob(function (blob) {
           saveAs(blob, "testing.png")
       })
   }

   render() {

       return (
           <div>
               <a onClick={this.saveCanvas}>Download as PNG</a>
      
               <Bar id="stackD" data={data} options={options} />
           </div>
       );
   }
}
export default StackedBar;
```

Answer (score 1):

another option is to use the chart ref, and then use the chart.js toBase64Image function. save this out as base64, convert to blob and save as a file using the file-saver package.

```
import { saveAs } from 'file-saver';

/**
 * @param b64Data
 * @param contentType
 * @param sliceSize
 * @returns {Blob}
 * @link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245767/creating-a-blob-from-a-base64-string-in-javascript
 */
const b64toBlob = (b64Data, contentType = '', sliceSize = 512) => {
  const byteCharacters = atob(b64Data);
  const byteArrays = [];

  for (let offset = 0; offset < byteCharacters.length; offset += sliceSize) {
    const slice = byteCharacters.slice(offset, offset + sliceSize);

    const byteNumbers = new Array(slice.length);
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-plusplus
    for (let i = 0; i < slice.length; i += 1) {
      byteNumbers[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i);
    }

    const byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
    byteArrays.push(byteArray);
  }

  return new Blob(byteArrays, { type: contentType });
};

... in component
  const chartRef = useRef(null);
... in jsx...


<Button
   onClick={() => {
   const b64 = chartRef.current.toBase64Image().replace('data:image/png;base64,', '');
   const content = b64toBlob(b64);
   const file = new File([content], 'Revenue_chart.png', { type: 'image/png' });
   saveAs(file);
  }}
  >
    img
</Button>
<Line data={data} options={options} ref={chartRef} />
```